# IIS10 delay accessing multiple domains bound to same site

Tags: php, dns, binding, localhost, iis-10

I see there are several questions similar, but none addressing the delay I am experiencing. I am using IIS 10 on Windows Server 2019 internally (intranet). The project is written in PHP and the data files are stored using MySQL. I have setup a site name WRD with a physical path E:\WRD.

[image]

The binding includes multiple domains

[image]

On my local system (and internal network), I can access the domain rw-wrd.com and the page comes up immediately, then I close that browser page and open the domain dallashistorian.com and the browser waits and my browser stalls and finally I get the message page cannot be display:

[image]

After a moment or two, I refresh and the page appears:

[image]

I am sure there is a simple explanation for this, but it has escaped me. It seems like there is a timing issue or a sharing of resources, etc. I am using $_SESSIONs and have considered that being the issue.

Any suggestions would be helpful. These website are active and can be accessed. I am curious if accessing the different domains immediately out-site the intranet has a similar issue. Any positive feedback will be appreciated.

Regards, Rich

Comment: HTTP 408 falls into the category of client errors. The 408 Request Timeout error means that the request you sent to the web server took longer than the server was prepared to wait. This can happen if the client takes too long to send the request or the server is too busy to handle it. This could be due to heavy internet traffic or a slow connection on your end.

Comment: Additional information: I bring up one site, which pops up quickly. then I request the second site (same browser on new tab) and that is when the timeout occurs. Is that a client issue or possibly a resource issue related to the IIS server/MySQL server? Why is the remote server not responding to the request for another domain located on the same server?

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description. Maybe you need to try monitoring the server's resource usage, including CPU, memory, and network utilization, during requests to see if any limits are hit. In addition, when the server hangs, crashes, or has poor performance, it is usually necessary to grab the server's thread stack (Thread Dump) for subsequent analysis. So I suggest you open a case through: https://support.microsoft.com, there will be professional technicians to assist you to grab the dump file and analyze it.